# How to customize admin edit page - custom type

Tags: custom-post-types

I create a custom post type to manager my custom form. How i can display my details data in admin dashboard. It may look like 
https://managewp.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/WooCommerce-Overview-Orders-Edit.png

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you are interested in Meta Boxes. In the picture, meta boxes are all over the place. You should take a look at

- WordPress [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function
- [Example How To Add Meta Boxes To Edit Area](http://wpengineer.com/1991/example-how-to-add-meta-boxes-to-edit-area/)
- [Meta Box Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/) to create metaboxes.